# How do I carry over a variable from one class to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to program a application that carries over user inputs from one page to the other where the pages are separated by classes. A problem I'm having is that the array output on page 2 isn't updating. Basically the output is just [] which is just the starting initialized variable. I've tried some solutions I've found on stack overflow such as calling it a global variable again at the init bit of the PageTwo class as well as trying to use PageOne.overall_data and using self.overall_data but the problem persists although there weren't any errors. This is a part of the code before I tried anything. I tried to cut out the irrelevant bits but I'm not sure if I cut out too much, feedback is much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter_nav as tknav
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
class App(tknav.Wrapper):

     def __init__(self):
          tknav.Wrapper.__init__(
            self,
            pages=[PageOne, PageTwo],
            start_state={'previous_page': None}
        )
          self.geometry('450x450')
          self.show_page('page_one')
class PageOne(tknav.Page):

    def __init__(self, parent):
          tknav.Page.__init__(self, parent, 'page_one')
          player_details = []
          global overall_data
          overall_data = []
          my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
          my_notebook.pack(pady = 15)
          my_notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
          my_frame1 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, width = "500", height = "500")
          def submit():                        #called every time inputs are made to be appended to player_details then overall_data
             player_details = []
             global overall_data
             player_details.append(name.get())
             player_details.append(health.get())
             player_details.append(ac.get())
             player_details.append(initiative.get())
             overall_data.append(player_details)
             overall_data = sorted(overall_data, key = lambda x:x[3])
             print(str(overall_data))
class PageTwo(tknav.Page):        #second page of the application

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tknav.Page.__init__(self, parent, 'page_two')

        tk.Label(
            self,
            text='Page Two'
        ).pack()

        tk.Button(
            self,
            text='Navigate to Page One',
            command=lambda: self.__navigate(),
        ).pack()

        line21 = tk.Label(self, text = str(overall_data), font = ('Times New Roman', 12))
        line21.place(x = 30, y  = 30, width = 100, height = 25)
    def __navigate(self):
        print('navigating to page one')
        self.navigate('page_one')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use 'self'. In `PageOne.__init()__`, you are defining lost of variables (`player_details`, `my_notebook`, `my_frame1`) that are just local and go out of scope at the end of the method. And what about submit()? I assume that it is supposed to be a member of PageOne too. Then it need to have `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Most of them don't need to be carried over to the next class except for overall_data, I've been struggling to understand self so when in regards to that I try to imitate other code I've seen and tweak it till it works. I tried to put self into the submit but then I get `TypeError: submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: The error message comes from where it is called. I cannot see that in your submitted code. `submit()` needs to be one indention level up and have a `self` argument. Then you can call it like `page_one_instance.submit()` or pass it as `page_one_instance.submit` as a callback. And please read an article on `self`. There's no way your code does what you want it to do.

Comment: Messing around with it a bit, it actually does seem to be working, the problem was that once player input was appended to the array, it didn't update the output. Since all the pages display at once at the beginning, the array displayed was simply the one used for initialization. Creating a new button to display the new array works instead. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data at the class level in `PageOne` like this:

```py
class PageOne(tknav.Page):
    overall_data = []
```

and use it everywhere like this:

```py
    PageOne.overall_data.append(player_details)
```

Comment: I tried to use PageOne.overall_data in the PageTwo class but it gave me (AttributeError: type object 'PageOne' has no attribute 'overall_data'). I used it like this: line21 = tk.Label(self, text = str(PageOne.overall_data), font = ('Times New Roman', 12)), I also tried overall_data = PageOne.overall_data.

Comment: So, did you put `overall_data` inside `class PageOne`?

Comment: Yep, but when I add overall_data outside of the init, I get a different problem where my submit function doesn't do anything to the overall_data when it's suppose to append into it. If I only add the overall_data outside the init and delete it from my init then there's a NameError.

Comment: And do you refer to it as ‘PageOne.overall_data’ *everywhere*?

Comment: Yep, except for right under the PageOne class like you did

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `tkinter_nav`, you can use its provided `app_state` to share data between pages:

```py
class App(tknav.Wrapper):
     def __init__(self):
        tknav.Wrapper.__init__(
            self,
            pages=[PageOne, PageTwo],
            start_state={'previous_page': None, 'overall_data': []} # added 'overall_data'
        )
        self.geometry('450x450')
        self.show_page('page_one')
```

Then you can access this shared data in each page by:

```py
self.app_state['overall_data']
```